# Users can't access any file of scripts folder in style library

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, style-library

In Sharepoint Online portal I have a scripts folder inside the style library. These scripts are used on some pages through the script editor webpart with script tag. The user, which I used to upload these scripts, can see them in style library and on pages. But the new user created by administration center on portal.office.com can't see files in style library and script files keep showing not found error (404) in browser console. How must I grant permissions for the new users?

Comment: Are the scripts published? The Style Library has versioning enabled by default, so you have to remember to publish a major version of files you put in there to make them available to all users.

Comment: Have you checked mentioned conditions in my answer to get it resolved ?

Comment: @DylanCristy the publish button is disabled. I don't know if the scripts published or not. Only user that uploaded them can see them.

Comment: Did your SharePoint Online environment's scripting capabilities ON?

Comment: @Hardik yes. Thanks for your attention I just resolved my problem. See answer below.

Comment: Thanks to post your resolution here. I am glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hardik I found the solution was to cancel check out and publish files. I just discovered the little arrow in a green square on each script file. These files were checked out and I cancelled the check out and published them. Thanks to everybody for help.

Comment: BTW I already suggested the same in my answer as well.. Here is the line... "Second, check to make sure all of your assets are checked in as major versions and approved if necessary."

Comment: @Hardik yes, that guided me to the right solution too. I will write your nick in my answer. For me there is difference between approved and published and I didn't get it right away.

Comment: If i helped you anyhow than you can help me by giving some credit to my given answer..:)

Comment: @Hardik my reputation is less than 15 so I cannot vote.

Comment: My bad luck man...

Comment: You can mark the answer as it is simple & clear for other users to get the idea from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try change the permission level of those users and add Manage Lists  list permission.

**OR**

Typically the Style Resources Reader group has restricted read to the root style library. This group contains all authenticated users by default. First check to see if this group exists on the library and does have the all authenticated users in it.

Second, check to make sure all of your assets are checked in as major versions and approved if necessary.

If all of these are correct, you could alter the Style Resources Readers group to have read permission on the library.

Comment: Did you tried above solution? is that works for you?